# Setting up a VPN in Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: networking, kali-linux, vpn

I just installed the latest version of Kali Linux, i.e., Kali Linux 2.0. 
I want to know how to set up a VPN in this version.

Comment: Which side of the connection are ya asking about? Or to be more precise, are you asking how to setup a connection to a pre-existing server or are you asking about setting up a server? And what is your past experience and what have ya already tried and/or got working previously? If these questions (specifically the first one) are addressed via an edit to your question it'll make answering possible.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search revealed this "A very detailed guide on how to setup VPN on Kali Linux and Ubuntu" http://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/03/01/setup-vpn-on-kali-linux/

Comment: If you can provide more information about your requirements then there may be alternatives to OpenVPN